# Figure out what values $(...).slideDown() is animating to

Tags: jquery, animation, height, slidedown

As far as I understand, jQuery does some magic measurement to figure out what the "normal" height of an element is, to be able to animate it with `.slideDown()`. Is there any way to get these measurements as soon as jQuery has them?

Specifically what I want to do is to start animate the html `scrollTop` to the bottom of a target that is about to be revealed.

Comment: when the animation and scroll are complete, where is the newly visible element? Is it above the top of the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, jquery's `height` already handles this "magic".  Native `offsetHeight` will return 0 for hidden elements but jquery's `height` will return their proper height.

Also, if you're curious about the magic.  They basically set the `{ position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", display: "block" }` on the element, check the height, then revert back to the original values.